# Multiple focus events from mouse click in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, mouselistener

When I click on a table cell, and then click on a second table cell, a number of mouse and focus events occur that I do not understand.  For example, clicking of cell (1, 0) and then on cell (2, 1) and then the Done button to display the sequence of events causes the following events:

1) Mouse Pressed on cell (1,0)
2) Focus Gained on cell (1,0)
3) Mouse Pressed on cell (1,0)  - why(?)
4) Mouse Pressed on cell (2,1)
5) Focus Lost on cell (1,0) - why(?)
6) Focus Lost on cell (2,1)
7) Focus Gained on cell (1,0) - why(?)
8) Focus Gained on cell (2,1) - why(?)
9) Focus Lost on cell (1,0) - why(?)
10) Focus lost on cell (2,1) - why(?)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER;
import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TestFocus {

    public ArrayList<String> mylog;
    public int number = 0;

    public TestFocus() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = createPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);    
    }

    public JPanel createPanel() {
        mylog = new ArrayList<>();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        TestTableModel tm = new TestTableModel();
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Test Table");
        JTable table = new JTable(tm);
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        TestTableCellEditor editor = new TestTableCellEditor();
        TestTableCellRenderer renderer = new TestTableCellRenderer();
        for (int i = 0; i < tm.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column = tcm.getColumn(i);
            column.setCellEditor(editor);
            column.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        }

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Done");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                for (String s : mylog) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        });

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.add(jsp);
        panel.add(btn);
        return panel;
    }

    class TestTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = { "Firstname", "Lastname", "Age" };
        private Object[][] data = { 
            { "John", "Smith", 29},
            { "Mary", "Thomas", 63},
            { "Peter", "Jones", 48} };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
            return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
        }

        public String getColumnClassName(int col) {
            if (col == 2) {
                return "Integer";
            } else {
                return "String";
            }
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return true;
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }

    public class TestTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
            implements TableCellEditor {
        JComponent component = new JTextField();

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

            ((JTextField)component).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                    mylog.add(++number + ") Mouse pressed: " +
                        value.toString() + ": r/c ("+row+"/"+column+")");
                }
            });

            ((JTextField)component).addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                    mylog.add(++number + ") Focus gained: " +
                        value.toString() + ": r/c ("+row+"/"+column+")");
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                    mylog.add(++number + ") FocusLost: " + 
                        value.toString() + ": r/c ("+row+"/"+column+")");
                }
            });

            if (value != null) {
                ((JTextField)component).setText(value.toString());
            } else {
                ((JTextField)component).setText("");
            }

            return (JTextField)component;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return ((JTextField)component).getText();
        }

    }

    public class TestTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements 
                TableCellRenderer {

        public TestTableCellRenderer() {
            this.setOpaque(true);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, final int row, int column) {

            DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
            Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                    isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (hasFocus) {
                c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }
            TestTableModel tm = (TestTableModel)table.getModel();
            int col = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
            String colname = tm.getColumnName(col);
            String type = tm.getColumnClassName(col);

            if (type.equals("Integer") || type.equals("Int")) {
                ((JLabel)c).setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
            } else {    // add padding 
                ((JLabel)c).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
                ((JLabel)c).setHorizontalAlignment(LEFT);
            }

            if (type.equals("String")) {
                String text = ((JLabel)c).getText();
                    ((JLabel)c).setToolTipText(text);
            }
           return c;
        }
    }     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestFocus();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getTableCellEditorComponent` method will be called very time the `JTable` gets rendered - a lot of times. Inside it you `textfield.addMouseListener()`. That means the listener will be added a lot of times. That's why you get many events instead of one (all these listeners are notified). In order to solve it, add the listeners only one time. You can add the listeners in constructor of this class.

For example:

```
public class TestTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    private JTextField component;

    public TestTableCellEditor() {
        component = new JTextField();
        component.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        component.addFocusListener(focusListener)
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return component.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        component.setText(value == null ? "" : String.valueOf(value));
        return component;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's cleared up the multiple events, but when I click the 2nd cell, it's focus is lost before it is gained, and the focus is never lost on clicking the first cell.
Not sure how to show the revised editor code